# jQuery each function for a group of elements (animate multiple selectors at the same time)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, grouping, each

I'm adding some animation to my online resume. Each job is in a div with a corresponding date range div.
I want each job div and date range div to fade from 0 to 1 opacity and move up the screen **together.**

Here's my function:

```
$(".job-box, .job-dates").each(function(i){
    var initialDelay = 500 * i;
    $(this).delay(initialDelay).animate({
        opacity:1,
        marginTop:"0px"
    },500);
});
```

But this animates **each div** rather than **grouping each job box div and date range div** together.

**I did try wrapping each div group in another div** and animating that instead but it doesn't work either. Maybe it's because the wrapper div stays at a height of 0? I can't figure out why the wrapper isn't the height of its contents...

**The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/kobraklean/m41xwck3/**

Any ideas?:)

Comment: uhm. you'll have to loop over one, and then from the one find the other (`$(this).next().addBack()`), then animate them together. https://jsfiddle.net/m41xwck3/1/

Comment: @KevinB perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that fixes this behavior is to only change the interval on every even/odd div. I adjusted your code like so and it works as I suspect you would want:

```
var i=0;
$(".job-box, .job-dates").each(function(i){
    var initialDelay = 500 * Math.floor(i/2);
    $(this).delay(initialDelay).animate({
        opacity:1,
        marginTop:"0px"
    },500);
});
```

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m41xwck3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

since you want to animate groups of related elements, you should either group elements within another element and animate that other element, or, select one element in the group, then from that element, select the other and animate them together.

The former would be simpler, but modifies your dom. Here's an example of the latter:

```js
    $(".job-box").each(function(i){
        var initialDelay = 100 * i;
     $(this)
          .next() // selects the next div, which is a .job-dates div
          .addBack() // appends the previous collection ($(this)) to this collection
          .delay(initialDelay).animate({
         opacity:1,
      marginTop:"0px"
     },350);
    });
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

.job-box {
  background-color: #b21d23;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 41.667%;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.job-box-left,
.job-dates-left {
  float: left;
}

.job-marker-left,
.job-marker-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.job-marker-left {
  right: -10px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #b21d23;
}

.job-marker-right {
  left: -10px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #b21d23;
}

.job-box h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0%;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.job-box h3 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.job-box p {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.job-dates-left p,
.job-dates-right p {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.job-dates {
  width: 16.667%;
}

.job-dates-right,
.job-box-right {
  float: right;
}

.job-box-right {
  clear: left;
}

.job-box-left {
  clear: right;
}

.job-box,
.job-dates {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job-box job-box-left">
  <div class="job-marker-left"></div>
  <h2>Job Title</h2>
  <h3>Company Name</h3>
  <p>Job Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur odio eget justo maximus, a fermentum ipsum tincidunt. Mauris id urna luctus, elementum purus ac, egestas nisl. Pellentesque laoreet felis ac blandit semper. Praesent
    volutpat fermentum aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="job-dates job-dates-left">
  <p>Aug '14 - Apr '16</p>
</div>

<div class="job-box job-box-right">
  <div class="job-marker-right"></div>
  <h2>Job Title</h2>
  <h3>Company Name</h3>
  <p>Job Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur odio eget justo maximus, a fermentum ipsum tincidunt. Mauris id urna luctus, elementum purus ac, egestas nisl. Pellentesque laoreet felis ac blandit semper. Praesent
    volutpat fermentum aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="job-dates job-dates-right">
  <p>Feb '12 - May '14</p>
</div>

<div class="job-box job-box-left">
  <div class="job-marker-left"></div>
  <h2>Job Title</h2>
  <h3>Company Name</h3>
  <p>Job Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur odio eget justo maximus, a fermentum ipsum tincidunt. Mauris id urna luctus, elementum purus ac, egestas nisl. Pellentesque laoreet felis ac blandit semper. Praesent
    volutpat fermentum aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="job-dates job-dates-left">
  <p>Feb '12 - May '14</p>
</div>

<div class="job-box job-box-right">
  <div class="job-marker-right"></div>
  <h2>Job Title</h2>
  <h3>Company Name</h3>
  <p>Job Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur odio eget justo maximus, a fermentum ipsum tincidunt. Mauris id urna luctus, elementum purus ac, egestas nisl. Pellentesque laoreet felis ac blandit semper. Praesent
    volutpat fermentum aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="job-dates job-dates-right">
  <p>Jun '12 - Aug '12</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m41xwck3/10/